# How to move the Y-axis label to the origin of the graph?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to replicate a graph as seen in the picture below, using LaTeX.

[image]

I have found [this tutorial](https://latexdraw.com/linear-regression-in-latex-using-tikz/) and have used it as a basis of creating the graph.

However, I struggle with moving the Y-axis to the origin as seen in the picture below. How can I move the Y-axis to the origin?

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 
% Required package
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\begin{axis}[
    xmin = -300, xmax = 100,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 7,
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.75\textwidth,
    xtick distance = 50,
    ytick distance = 1,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
]
% plot data line code
\addplot[teal, only marks] table[x = t, y = x] {result.dat};

\end{axis}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, show us your table `result.dat`.

Comment: Try  `axis x line=center, axis y line=center`... (section 4.9.9 on a recent pgfplots manual, page 272)

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to help you since you not provide table `result.dat`, so we nove where are coordinates of your marks. If I replace it by dummy line between coordinates `(-273,-273)` and (100,7), I get the following diagram (based on your code fragment):

[image]

Is this what you looking for? The MWE (Minimal Working Example) for above diagram is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% Required package
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 4,
    xmin = -300,    xmax = 100, xlabel={T (\si{\celsius})},
    ymin = -300,    ymax = 10,  ylabel={V},
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
             ]
% plot data line code
\addplot coordinates {(-273,-273) (90,7)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When you will provide missed data, I can correct diagram accordingly.

**Edit:**
However, it seems that you ma looking for the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% Required package
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num = 4,
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    xmin = -300,    xmax = 100, xlabel={T (\si{\celsius})},
    ymin = -300,    ymax = 50,  ylabel={V},
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
             ]
% plot data line code
\addplot coordinates {(-273,-273) (90,7)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```